# Train accuracy decreases with train loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I wrote this very simple code

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(13000, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='relu', trainable=False))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, input_dim=13000, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer='adam', metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=X_train.shape[0], epochs=1000000, verbose=1)
```

The data is MNIST but only for digits '0' and '1'.
I have a very strange issue, where the loss is monotonically decreasing to zero, as expected, yet the accuracy instead of increasing, is also decreasing.

Here is a sample output

```
12665/12665 [==============================] - 0s 11us/step - loss: 0.0107 - accuracy: 0.2355
Epoch 181/1000000

12665/12665 [==============================] - 0s 11us/step - loss: 0.0114 - accuracy: 0.2568
Epoch 182/1000000

12665/12665 [==============================] - 0s 11us/step - loss: 0.0128 - accuracy: 0.2726
Epoch 183/1000000

12665/12665 [==============================] - 0s 11us/step - loss: 0.0133 - accuracy: 0.2839
Epoch 184/1000000

12665/12665 [==============================] - 0s 11us/step - loss: 0.0134 - accuracy: 0.2887
Epoch 185/1000000

12665/12665 [==============================] - 0s 11us/step - loss: 0.0110 - accuracy: 0.2842
Epoch 186/1000000

12665/12665 [==============================] - 0s 11us/step - loss: 0.0101 - accuracy: 0.2722
Epoch 187/1000000

12665/12665 [==============================] - 0s 11us/step - loss: 0.0094 - accuracy: 0.2583
```

Since we only have two classes, the benchmark for lowest possible accuracy should be 0.5, and furthermore we are monitoring accuracy on the training set, so it should very going up to 100%, I expect overfitting and I am overfitting according to the loss function.

At the final epoch, this is the situation

```
12665/12665 [==============================] - 0s 11us/step - loss: 9.9710e-06 - accuracy: 0.0758
```

a 7% accuracy when the worst theoretical possibility if you guess randomly is 50%. This is no accident. Something is going on here.

Can anyone see the problem?

**Entire code**

```
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import keras
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from keras import layers
import warnings

class EarlyStoppingByLossVal(Callback):
    def __init__(self, monitor='val_loss', value=0.00001, verbose=0):
        super(Callback, self).__init__()
        self.monitor = monitor
        self.value = value
        self.verbose = verbose

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        current = logs.get(self.monitor)
        if current is None:
            warnings.warn("Early stopping requires %s available!" % self.monitor, RuntimeWarning)

        if current < self.value:
            if self.verbose > 0:
                print("Epoch %05d: early stopping THR" % epoch)
            self.model.stop_training = True

def load_mnist():

    mnist = keras.datasets.mnist
    (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()


    train_images = np.reshape(train_images, (train_images.shape[0], train_images.shape[1] * train_images.shape[2]))
    test_images = np.reshape(test_images, (test_images.shape[0], test_images.shape[1] * test_images.shape[2]))
    train_labels = np.reshape(train_labels, (train_labels.shape[0],))
    test_labels = np.reshape(test_labels, (test_labels.shape[0],))

    train_images = train_images[(train_labels == 0) | (train_labels == 1)]
    test_images = test_images[(test_labels == 0) | (test_labels == 1)]

    train_labels = train_labels[(train_labels == 0) | (train_labels == 1)]
    test_labels = test_labels[(test_labels == 0) | (test_labels == 1)]
    train_images, test_images = train_images / 255, test_images / 255

    return train_images, train_labels, test_images, test_labels



X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = load_mnist()
train_acc = []
train_errors = []
test_acc = []
test_errors = []

width_list = [13000]
for width in width_list:
    print(width)

    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(width, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='relu', trainable=False))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1, input_dim=width, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer='adam', metrics=["accuracy"])

    callbacks = [EarlyStoppingByLossVal(monitor='loss', value=0.00001, verbose=1)]
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=X_train.shape[0], epochs=1000000, verbose=1, callbacks=callbacks)


    train_errors.append(model.evaluate(X_train, y_train)[0])
    test_errors.append(model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)[0])
    train_acc.append(model.evaluate(X_train, y_train)[1])
    test_acc.append(model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)[1])


plt.plot(width_list, train_errors, marker='D')
plt.xlabel("width")
plt.ylabel("train loss")
plt.show()
plt.plot(width_list, test_errors, marker='D')
plt.xlabel("width")
plt.ylabel("test loss")
plt.show()
plt.plot(width_list, train_acc, marker='D')
plt.xlabel("width")
plt.ylabel("train acc")
plt.show()
plt.plot(width_list, test_acc, marker='D')
plt.xlabel("width")
plt.ylabel("test acc")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could it be that you have set your only hidden layer to freeze its weights by `trainable=False`?

Comment: Yes and I had a good reason to do so, that's irrelevant for the matter at hand and is reproducable also with trainable=True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear activation in the last layer for a (binary) classification problem is **meaningless**; change your last layer to:

```
model.add(layers.Dense(1, input_dim=width, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Linear activations for the last layer are used for regression problems and not for classification ones.

Comment: May I add that it's not possible to compute the binary crossentropy loss function with a value which is not in the (0, 1) interval?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco but apparently the implementation is such that it does not produce any error

Comment: Thank you, that does seem to fix the issue. Can you explain why?

Comment: @OriaGruber *very* roughly speaking (w/o going through the theory & math of ML), in classification you need something to limit the output to [0, 1], and a linear activation for sure does not do that; plus, as already mentioned, cross-entropy is not even defined mathematically for outputs greater than 1 (despite the fact that Keras does not throw a computation error).

Comment: I kind of wanted to use a linear activation to gaurantee a 0 loss. This makes the final layer to solving Ax=b where A has more columns than rows and has full rank probably, which gives us zero MSE loss.

Comment: @OriaGruber i don't follow (you use cross-entropy loss, and not MSE). There is a whole (math) theory behind classification, which cannot be re-iterated here. Plus, SO is about *implementation* issues (such as the one you specifically asked - please see the **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info)); theoretical issues should be posted to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco No, the binary crossentropy can be computed with any value, you just would not get the expected results, you could even get nans or negative losses as a result.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy yes you're right, let me be more specific: it can't be computed mathematically. Of course in programming you're allowed to manage errors and return any specific value.